# How to store 2D arrays in a single array and print them in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, multidimensional-array, c++17

Is this is the right way to store and print?

```
int array[5];
int a1[3][3], a2[3][3], a3[3][3], a4[3][3], a5[3][3];

int array[0] = a1[3][3];
int array[1] = a2[3][3];
int array[2] = a3[3][3];
int array[3] = a4[3][3];
int array[4] = a5[3][3];

 for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
 for(int j=0;j<3;j++) {
     a1[i][j] = 0;
 }
}
```

Similarly, filling the rest arrays.

Now Printing,

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
cout<<array[i];
}
```

did n't get the expected output.

**How to print the a1,a2,a3,a4 and a5 from array?**

Comment: What is your output? Is it the expected? I guess no, so it isn't the right way to store and print. If you use C++11 or even C++17, why do you don't use std::vector or std::array?

Comment: What did you expect to accomplish by apparently copying the values from an initialized array to a 2nd array and afterwards printing those garbage values, from the 2nd array after finally initializing the first array, from where the values got copied from, ***after they were already copied***?

Answer (score 1):

So instead of using old plain c-arrays, use the in-build C++ std::array, if you want fixed-sized arrays. If the range should be dynamic you can switch `std::array` with `std::vector`. Look up the different definitions:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

// a 2D-array is nothing else, than an array containing anotehr array
// what we do, is to define an array with size 3 containing an array with size 3 
// this equals int a[3][3];
// this we do 5 times as requested
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a1 =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a2 =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a3 =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a4 =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3> a5 =  {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};


// now for the array which should contain the other arrays:
// we define a size of 5
// and it should contain the array which contains the array both of size 3
std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 3>, 5> the_array;

int main() {

    // we directly assign the array specifier to the value 
    // which should contain the specified array
    the_array[0] = a1;
    the_array[1] = a2;
    the_array[2] = a3;
    the_array[3] = a4;
    the_array[4] = a5;

    // now we cannot print the arrays at once, 
    // we have to iterate "down" to the int to print it

    for(auto sub_array2D : the_array) { // iterate over the array containing the 5 arrays

        for(auto  sub_array1D : sub_array2D) { // now iterate over one array in the array of the 2d array

            for(auto elem : sub_array1D) { // at last, access the int element and print it out
                std::cout << elem << " ";
            }
            std::cout << "\t"; // formatting
        }
        std::cout << "\n"; // formatting
    }

    return 0;
}
```